# Transform two lines separated by a line into one line

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I'm trying to find the parameters sent in all POST requests by looking at my production Rails log files. Right now I'm just using the following:

```
grep 'Started POST.*\/[fr]' log/production.log
```

This shows me when the POSTs happen but not the parameters. What I'd like is to do something along the lines of:

1. Store the line in sed's hold buffer when it encounters the regex above
2. Print the contents of the hold buffer and the current line when it encounters "Parameters:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood you need to display line with regex and the following line. `grep` can do it itself:

```
grep -A1 'Started POST.*\/[fr]' log/production.log
```

with `sed` it will look like:

```
sed -n '/Started POST.*\/[fr]/{N;p}' log/production.log
```

or if not all following lines may content "Parameters" and you need only them:

```
sed -n '/Started POST.*\/[fr]/{N;/Parameters/p}' log/production.log
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! Thanks! I'll accept it as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: what I actually went with was "grep -A2 'Started POST.*\/[fr]' log/production.log | grep -v Processing". The reason is that before the "Parameters" line there's a line that starts with "Processing" and I couldn't figure out how to get that out using just sed.

Comment: `sed -n '/Started POST.*\/[fr]/{N;/Parametrs/{s/.*\n//;p}}'`

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
sed -n '/Started POST.*\/[fr]/h;/Parameters/{H;g;p;q}'
```

It holds the first line and prints it and the line containing "Parameters". Only the first set of lines will be printed.

Comment: That looks like it also prints out every line which has "Parameters", not just the first one which comes after the line matched by /Started Post.*\/[fr]/

Comment: @higginbotham: Add a `q` after the `p`. I'll update my answer.